# What are the steps involved in running the same python script in parallel in amazon ec2 or picloud

Tags: python, parallel-processing, amazon-ec2, cloud

I need some help on a parallel processing task that I am trying to complete asap.

It simply involves splitting a largeish dataframe into smaller chunks and running the same script on each chunk.

I think this is called embarassingly parallel.

I would be very grateful if there's someone out there who could suggest a template to achieve this task using either amazon cloud services or picloud.

I have made initial forays into amazon ec2 and picloud (the script I will run on each data chunk is in python) but realise that I may 
not figure out how to do it in either without some help.

So, any pointers would be greatly appreciated. I'm just looking for basic help (to those in the know), such as the main steps involved in setting up parallel cores or cpus using either ec2 or picloud or whatever, running the script in parallel, and saving the script output i.e. the script writes the result of its calculation to a csv file.

i'm running ubuntu 12.04, my python 2.7 script doesnt involve non-stand libraries, just os and csv. the script isn't complex, just the data is too big for my machine and timeframe.

Comment: How large is the data? Is it in one large file or many smaller files?

Comment: The data is about 50mb on disc. I ran the script on a tiny fraction of that, which took 80 mins to complete. Time seems to scale linearly, and I think I'm looking at processing time of 1000 hours at that rate! That's when I thought of maybe splitting it over many different cores.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This script uses the cloud library for Python from PiCloud, and should be run locally.

```
# chunks is a list of filenames (you'll need to define generate_chunk_files)
chunks = generate_chunk_files('large_dataframe')
for chunk in chunks:
    # stores each chunk in your PiCloud bucket
    cloud.bucket.put(chunk)

def process_chunk(chunk):
    """Runs on PiCloud"""

    # saves chunk object locally
    cloud.bucket.get(chunk)
    f = open(chunk, 'r')
    # process the data however you want

# asynchronously runs process_chunk on the cloud for all chunks
job_ids = cloud.map(process_chunk, chunks)
```

Use the [Realtime Cores](http://docs.picloud.com/realtime_cores.html) feature to allocate a specific number of cores.

Comment: Thanks very much for this BrainCore, I'm going to try to implement it now on a test case, I'll post my results. BTW, I don't have enough reputation to upvote your answer in the meantime, even though I'd like to!

Comment: Events have taken a turn here and I may not be able to post results for a while. In the meantime I'm more than happy to accept this as the answer to what I was looking for. Thanks again BrainCore.